# How to update Tkinter label when reading from a text file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, live

I am new to python so I appreciate any help. I'm trying to build a gps speedometer and use Tkinter to make a gui to display the info. I'm having difficulty getting Tkinter to update the displayed text. For the current method (not shown in the code below), I have one script running and outputting 2 text files named "MPH.txt" and "Time.txt" with values such as "0.00" and "232445.500" respectively. This happens continuously and writes over the old files.
Here is the code I have to read and display them. It will read it once and display the correct data, but I cant get it to update no matter what approach I take to forcing it to clear the text in each widget. I can close and open the window and it updates, but would like to start it and have it update on its own.

```
import serial
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("GPS Speedometer")
win.geometry('1920x720')

i=1
while True:
        if i == 1:
                time_text=tk.Label(text="Current Time (UTC)").grid(row=0, col$
                with open("Time.txt", "r") as t:
                        tk.Label(win, text=t.read()).grid(row=1, column=0)
                        t.close()

                speed_text=tk.Label(text="Current Speed (Knots)").grid(row=2,$
                with open("MPH.txt", "r") as s:
                        tk.Label(win, text=s.read()).grid(row=3, column=0)
                        s.close()

                exitButton=tk.Button(win, text='exit', command=win.destroy).g$
                i=i-1
        else:
                i=i+1

        tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a while or for loop in a GUI because it interferes with the GUI's mainloop. You have to add your code to the mainloop with the after method. Like this (plus a lot of other fixes):

```
import tkinter as tk

def loop():
    with open("Time.txt", "r") as t:
        time_text.config(text=t.read())
    with open("MPH.txt", "r") as s:
        speed_text.config(text=s.read())
    win.after(500, loop) # run every 500 milliseconds

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("GPS Speedometer")

# using 2 lines per label is very important to make this work!
lbl=tk.Label(text="Current Time (UTC)")
lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
time_text = tk.Label(win, text='loading')
time_text.grid(row=1, column=1)

lbl=tk.Label(text="Current Speed (Knots)")
lbl.grid(row=2,column=0)
speed_text = tk.Label(win, text='loading')
speed_text.grid(row=2, column=1)

exitButton=tk.Button(win, text='exit', command=win.destroy)
exitButton.grid()

loop() # start your loop
tk.mainloop() # start the mainloop
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help with showing me exactly how to go about it!